# Broadcast event and on are not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to generate broadcast an event from one controller and listen to it another one. But the result is not being displayed on the DOM , though there is no error . And also when I displaying normal $scope variables from both the controllers it is working . Just the broadcast and on are not working and as there is no error so I am not ale to debugg

```
oneApp.controller("twoController",["$log","$scope","$rootScope",function($log,$scope,$rootScope){
var str ="sent from twoController ";
$scope.hey = 215;
$rootScope.$broadcast("hey",str);

}])

oneApp.controller("twoChildController",    ["$log","$scope","$rootScope",function($log,$scope,$rootScope){
//var str ="sent from twoController ";
//$scope.display = str;
$scope.$on("hey",function(event,str){
$scope.display = str;
});

}])
```

So could someone please help me to resolve this ?

Comment: Try `$scope.$parent.$broadcast("hey", str);`

Comment: Maybe remove the `event` argument from $on function argument.

Comment: Is the function in the $scope.$on callback being called? you can check that with a console.log("Callback being called"); Please, check it and tell us if the log is being shown in the console. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, controller1 initiated first and then controller2. When controller1 initiated broadcast event has occurred and controller2 not yet initiated i.e. $on not yet registered. You can use $timeout.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

//controllers declaration
app.controller('myCtrl1',function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout){
  $scope.name = "Roger";
  
  $timeout(function(){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('hey',$scope.name);
  });      
    
});

app.controller('myCtrl2',function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.$on('hey',function(event,name){
      $scope.name=name;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp"> 

<div class="div1" ng-controller="myCtrl1"> 
     <span>myCtrl1 : {{name}}</span>
</div> 

<div class="div2" ng-controller="myCtrl2"> 
    <span>myCtrl2 : {{name}}</span> 
</div> 
 
</body>
```

Comment: That was the exact issue :) it's working now , Thank you. Just one small doubt what happens when we use the $timeout service without any delay ? Does it gets timed out immediately and the callback function gets called ?

Comment: $timeout put your work into queue to be run after current digest cycle.

Comment: Yes that I know I just wanted to know about the time that we provide what happens when we do not provide anything

Answer (score 0):

Try in given way:

**Define all your broadcast in some main controller like:**

```
$rootScope.broadcast.actions = {
        hey : 'hey'
        //all broadcast
}
```

**Broadcast send:**

```
$rootScope.$broadcast($rootScope.broadcast.actions.hey,{str});
```

**Broadcast receive:**

```
$scope.$on($rootScope.broadcast.actions.hey, function (event,str){
    $scope.display = str;
});
```